# Send the value of javascript variable to html

Tags: javascript, html, blockchain, solidity

I am unable to send the value of javascript variale 'userResults' to .html.
I want to display the contents of the form in tabular form.
Can you tell me a workaround for this?

This is in index.html

```
<form onSubmit="App.retrieveTransaction();" class="form2">

              <h1 class="text-center">Retrieve transactions</h1>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="enterregnoselect">Reg No:</label><input id ="enterregnoselect" class="form-control" type ="text" required/>
              </div>

              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >Retrieve</button>
              <hr /> 

              <table class="table">
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th scope="col">Date</th>
                      <th scope="col">Name</th>
                      <th scope="col">Item</th>
                      <th scope="col">Credit</th>
                      <th scope="col">Debit</th>
                      <th scope="col">Price</th>
                      <th scope="col">Qty</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody id="userResults">
                  </tbody>
                </table>
                <hr/>
              </form>
```

This is the retrieveTransaction function in app.js called on submitting the form in index.html

```
retrieveTransaction: function() {
    var transactionInstance;
    var enteredregno = $('#enterregnoselect').val();
    // var enteredregno = "0015/55";

    App.contracts.Payment.deployed().then(function(instance) {
      transactionInstance = instance;
      return transactionInstance.transactionCount();
    }).then(function(transactionCount) {
      var userResults = $("#userResults");
      userResults.empty();

      for (var i = 1; i <= transactionCount; i++) {
        transactionInstance.transactions(i).then(function(transaction) {
          var date = transaction[0];
          var regno = transaction[1];
          var name = transaction[2];
          var item = transaction[3];
          var credit = transaction[4];
          var debit = transaction[5];
          var price = transaction[6];
          var qty = transaction[7];

          if(enteredregno == regno) {
            var userTemplate = "<tr><th>" + date + "</th><td>" + name + "</td><td>" + item + "</td></tr>" + credit + "</th><td>" + debit + "</td><td>" + price + "</td></tr>" + qty + "</td></tr>";
            userResults.append(userTemplate); 
          }       
        });
      }
    });
```

Comment: Any console errors?

Comment: Can you show us the errors of the console?

Comment: I am using a lite-server, so can't view the value of the variable 'userResults' with console.log(). At the time of compilation, there are no errors